# json.parse triggers cross-origin error in React / MERN

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I have a data structure that when I `console.log` it, it works just fine:

`console.log(JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills);`

But when I pass the result of `JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills` to a component within my application, the whole thing crashes with a cross-origin error.

I can't understand why because I have enabled CORS on all of my data coming from the API, you can even see it in the request headers:

[image]

Here is the UI component that (when I make it map over the result of JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills) just crashes with a cross-origin error.:

```
    if(values) {
    return values.skills_required.map((skill, idx) => {
      return (
        <div className="input-group">
            <select 
                  onChange={e => updateSkill(e, idx)} 
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control">
                  <option>Select an option...</option>


            {JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills && JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills.map((q, w) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(q));
            console.log(w)
                  return(
                              <option 
                                key={w}
                                value={JSON.stringify(q)}>
                                 {JSON.stringify(q)}

                                </option> 

                              )})}


               </select>
              <div className="input-group-append">
                  <button 
                        className="btn btn-outline-danger mb-3" 
                        type="button" 
                        id="button-addon2" 
                        onClick={() => removeSkill(idx)}>x
                   </button>
              </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    };
  };
```

The part that really confuses me is that I can manipulate the exact same resulting data object in other parts of the application without even needing to `JSON.parse` the result, however the issue seems to be an underlying problem with the data representation itself.

`console.log(values.category2.needed_skills);` returns `undefined`

`console.log(JSON.parse([values.category2]).needed_skills)` returns exactly what I need to map over in my UI component above - yet for some reason when I JSON.parse in the UI component it crashes, and when I **dont** call JSON.parse in the UI, everything is fine (except that I cant map over the array):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For JSON.parse to work, you have to wrap it in a try-catch block.

In your case it would be:

```
if(values) {
let category2 = [];
try {
    category2 = JSON.parse([values.category2]);
} catch(e) {console.log(e)}
return values.skills_required.map((skill, idx) => {
  return (
    <div className="input-group">
        <select 
              onChange={e => updateSkill(e, idx)} 
              type="text"
              className="form-control">
              <option>Select an option...</option>


        {category2.needed_skills && category2.needed_skills.map(...)}
    ...
  );
);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is an acceptable solution?